# Parallel executing commands and wait

Tags: bash

I have a set of scripts, e.g.

```
01_some_stuff1
02_some_stuff2
03_some_stuff3a
03_some_stuff3b
04_some_stuff4a
04_some_stuff4b
```

These scripts should run ordered by their number and scripts with the same number should run in parallel.

My first idea was to iterate the possible numbers

```
for n in $(seq -f %02.0f 0 99); do
    for s in "${n}_*"; do
        export CURRENT_JOB="${s}"
        "${s}" &
    done
    wait
done
```

Is this a safe method? Is there a more elegant solution that also allows to set a different environment for the inner loop elements?

Comment: It is actually not a safe method. If the script `04_some_4c` is very short and finishes before `04_some_4a`, your script would run `05_some5a` while 4a is still running because `wait` waits only on the last job which was started in the background. I suggest a solution where you save the PID of the started process (`$!`) in an array. Then you can iterate over it and wait for every process.

Comment: @MoritzSauter: The bash manpage says that "If  n  is  not  given, all currently active child processes are waited for" not only the last started job

Comment: Oh sry, you are right. mixed that up. Have you tried your idea?

Comment: @MoritzSauter: Of course, but that is no prove of correctness in concurrent environments

Comment: Are your scripts on the `PATH`? Because otherwise the Snippet does not work.

Comment: @MoritzSauter: The example is somewhat simplified. The original uses a full path; otherwise it would not have worked at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real change you need is to avoid quoting the `*` in your pattern. If you are using `bash` 4.0 or later, you can use brace expansion to eliminate the dependency on `seq`.

```
# for n in $(seq -f %02.0f 0 99); do
for n in {00..99}; do
    for s in "${n}"_*; do
        export CURRENT_JOB="${s}"
        "${s}" &
    done
    wait
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Don't barf if no matching files when globbing
shopt -s nullglob

for n in $(printf "%02d " {1..4}); do
   # Get list (array) of matching scripts
   scripts=( ${n}_* )
   if [ ${#scripts[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
      parallel --dry-run -k 'CURRENT_JOB={} ./{}' ::: ${scripts[@]}
   fi
   echo barrier
done
```

**Sample Output**

```
CURRENT_JOB=01_some_stuff1 ./01_some_stuff1
barrier
CURRENT_JOB=02_some_stuff2 ./02_some_stuff2
barrier
CURRENT_JOB=03_some_stuff3a ./03_some_stuff3a
CURRENT_JOB=03_some_stuff3b ./03_some_stuff3b
CURRENT_JOB=03_some_stuff3c ./03_some_stuff3c
barrier
CURRENT_JOB=04_some_stuff4a ./04_some_stuff4a
CURRENT_JOB=04_some_stuff4b ./04_some_stuff4b
barrier
```

Remove the `echo barrier` and `--dry-run` to actually run it properly.